# How to query in dataframe combined with .shift()

Tags: python, pandas, shift

I have a temporary df like

```
tmp = df.loc[(df['Home Team'] == team) | (df['Away Team']== team)]
```

I would like to get a shifted value of a specific row. I tried

```
tmp.loc[(df['Primary Key'] == key)].shift(1)
```

but this obviously reduces the df first, so shift(1) will result in a non existing row. Any help to achieve this?

Comment: Can you add some data sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first shifting column and then compare:

```
tmp.loc[(tmp['Primary Key'].shift(1) == key)]
```